# Lua C API - loading multiple files with variables and functions of the same names

Tags: c++, lua, embedded-language

Say I have two Lua files which I'll be using from the standard Lua C API, that share a common library:

common.lua

```
function printHello(name)
    print("Hello from " .. name)
end
```

file1.lua

```
require "common"
local scriptName = "file1"

function doSomething()
    printHello(scriptName)
end
```

file2.lua

```
require "common"
local scriptName = "file2"

function doSomething()
    printHello(scriptName)
end
```

Now say I want to have both file*.lua files share the **same** `lua_State`. **Without changing any of the Lua code**, how can I load the files in way such that I can call a specific `doSomething()`?

Is there a way I can move "everything" from the loaded files (functions, variables, tables) it into a global table within the `lua_State` using the script-name (or whatever) as the key? Also, is there a way I can do this such that file1.lua and file2.lua can share the "in memory" version of common.lua?

I am using Lua 5.1.

Thanks!

Comment: The way you'd do this changed a lot between Lua 5.1 and 5.2. What version of Lua are you using exactly?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica 5.1. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you define local functions and return them instead of defining global variables and relying on games with the global environment.

Comment: You can give separate `_G` to each `file*.lua` by implementing your own `require`.  Both `_G1` and `_G2` would inherit standard Lua globals and globals created by `common.lua`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Coming back to this a couple months later, how would this be done in Lua 5.2? I can create a new question if you'd prefer.

Comment: @Addy That should probably be a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it in pure Lua 5.1:

```lua
file1_env = setmetatable({}, {__index = _G})
local file1_chunk = loadfile('file1.lua')
setfenv(file1_chunk, file1_env)
file1_chunk()

file2_env = setmetatable({}, {__index = _G})
local file2_chunk = loadfile('file2.lua')
setfenv(file2_chunk, file2_env)
file2_chunk()

file1_env.doSomething() -- prints "Hello from file1"
file2_env.doSomething() -- prints "Hello from file2"
```

What's going on is you're changing the environment that each file's chunk runs in, so instead of putting their `doSomething` functions in the global environment and thus stomping each other, they go in their own local environment (which uses a metatable so they can use things that are in the global environment like `require` and `print`). And as requested, `common.lua` only has to run once, as you'll see if you put something like `printHello('common')` at the end of it.

If you want to do this from C, all of the functionality I used can be straightforwardly converted to the C API, like this:

```c
#include <lua5.1/lua.h>
#include <lua5.1/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.1/lauxlib.h>

int main(void) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    /* stack is empty */
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    /* -1: file1_env */
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    /* -2: file1_env, -1: file1_env_mt */
    lua_pushvalue(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
    /* -3: file1_env, -2: file1_env_mt, -1: _G */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    /* -2: file1_env, -1: file1_env_mt */
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    /* -1: file1_env */
    luaL_loadfile(L, "file1.lua");
    /* -2: file1_env, -1: file1_chunk */
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
    /* -3: file1_env, -2: file1_chunk, -1: file1_env */
    lua_setfenv(L, -2);
    /* -2: file1_env, -1: file1_chunk */
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    /* -1: file1_env */
    lua_setglobal(L, "file1_env");
    /* stack is empty */
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    /* -1: file2_env */
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    /* -2: file2_env, -1: file2_env_mt */
    lua_pushvalue(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
    /* -3: file2_env, -2: file2_env_mt, -1: _G */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    /* -2: file2_env, -1: file2_env_mt */
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    /* -1: file2_env */
    luaL_loadfile(L, "file2.lua");
    /* -2: file2_env, -1: file2_chunk */
    lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
    /* -3: file2_env, -2: file2_chunk, -1: file2_env */
    lua_setfenv(L, -2);
    /* -2: file2_env, -1: file2_chunk */
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    /* -1: file2_env */
    lua_setglobal(L, "file2_env");
    /* stack is empty */
    lua_getglobal(L, "file1_env");
    /* -1: file1_env */
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "doSomething");
    /* -2: file1_env, -1: file1_env.doSomething */
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    /* -1: file1_env */
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    /* stack is empty */
    lua_getglobal(L, "file2_env");
    /* -1: file2_env */
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "doSomething");
    /* -2: file2_env, -1: file2_env.doSomething */
    lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    /* -1: file2_env */
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    /* stack is empty */

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the C API, should I save the corresponding `file1_env` and `file2_env1` into a global table so I can retrieve them as needed?

Comment: I don't understand how `local file1_env = setmetatable({}, {__index = _G})` and `local file1_env = setmetatable({}, {__index = _G})` translate to the C API? How would I load a file into a variable via the C API?

Comment: @Addy I just edited in how you'd do the same thing in C.

Comment: This will be massively useful. Thank you so much.